# General form of eigenvectors of spin operators for higher spin systems

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin

On this wiki page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_(physics)#Higher_spins, I found the generalized formula of spin matrices for any arbitrary spin $s$. The $a$th row and $b$th column of $S_x$, $S_y$ and $S_z$ should be in the following form:

$(S_x)_{ab}=\frac{\hbar}{2}(\delta_{a,b+1}+\delta_{a+1,b})\sqrt{(s+1)(a+b-1)-ab}$

$(S_y)_{ab}=\frac{i\hbar}{2}(\delta_{a,b+1}-\delta_{a+1,b})\sqrt{(s+1)(a+b-1)-ab}$

$(S_z)_{ab}=\hbar(s+1-a)\delta_{a,b}$

Is there anyway I could also generalize the eigenvectors of $S_x$, $S_y$ and $S_z$? It seems like the eigenvectors are also following some sort of pattern, but I couldn't find a clever way to generalize them.

Comment: You have 3 incompatible versions of $S_x$; it is kinda clear you meant x,y,z but copied wrongly. Why don't you do the standard scheme of forming an arbitrary direction linear combination of them and then diagonalising the resulting matrix? It will be tedious, but you can get somewhere. Or use Clebsch-Gordon, 3-j, or Wigner's D, and get the answer basically directly?

Comment: Find eigenvectors of $S_z$ (which is already diagonal), then rotate by $\pi/2$ in an appropriate direction to obtain the eigenvectors of $S_x$ and $S_y$.